# ASP.NET MVC: Passing a user control a list of 'something'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I'm wanting to have a strongly typed user control that accepts the class `PaginatedList<T>`

What will my signature for this user control look like and how do I render it?

At the moment I have this as my signature for the user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Project.Models.PaginatedList<Project.Models.Product>>" %>
```

Obviously this doesn't work when I pass a PaginatedList that holds something other than a product. Like here, when I want to send it a PaginatedList of news items:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Pagination", Model.NewsItems); %>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try making your control less strongly-typed and use something like `ViewUserControl<IEnumerable>`. Or, if you need some of the specific functionality of your PaginatedList, try creating a weakly-typed interface for your PaginatedList class and do `ViewUserControl<IPaginatedList>`.